# Is "to go + (onomatopoeia)" a recognized pattern?

Tags: terminology, onomatopoeia

Multiple times I saw that "to go" is used with strange things, especially in memes:

- [go brrr](https://knowyourmeme.com/memes/money-printer-go-brrr)
- [go woo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5-CxCUZsDHc)
- to go boom

But I don't see such scheme to be listed in [a dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/to+go) as phrasal verbs or idiomatic phrases.

How this thing is called? Is it still a sort of phrasal verb? Is a sort of [verbing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conversion_(word_formation)#Verbing), applied to onomatopoeia? Is this usage of "go" even described somewhere? Can other words instead of "go" serve this function?

Comment: I asked him if he was cold. He went "Brrrr".

Comment: Basic research. '**go**: to produce a noise:
I think I heard the doorbell go (= ring) just now. / 
I wish my computer would stop going "beep" whenever I do something wrong.' [[CED](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/go)]

Comment: Wasn't there some kind of controversial question here a while  ago about a Lou Reed song?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth But isn't there a more general use in this (let me call it 'stretched' use of 'go'?  Things or people can 'go crazy' or 'bananas' (you can 'send' them crazy - and 'turn' crazy' too).  The best way I can describe such verbs are that they are being used as 'wild cards.  And there are wild card nouns as well as verbs.  'thing' springs to mind:  "He has a thing about violets".

Comment: This is the Path metaphor theme. You follow the Path and "go" to various metaphoric "places", like _crazy_. Making noises is a different sense, of ordinary behavior: the bee goes 'buzz', the computer goes 'hmmm', ...

Comment: @Tuffy When verbs are 'totally bleached of meaning' ('semantic bleaching'), becoming merely functional, they're known as 'delexical verbs'. Take a hike. Have a bath.  Make a speech. Give a cry of relief. Do your hair. Hang a right.  John's pointing out the metaphor theme makes things less clear-cut; obviously the usages came from somewhere, and obviously someone is considerate of where they came from.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Thank you.  'semantic bleaching:  I confess I haven't heard that before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the definitions given by Oxford Dictionaries is 'make a sound of a specified kind'. This is a common usage in informal speech and when teaching animal noises to children:

> The cow goes moo.

> The balloon went bang.

Comment: I seem to remember some kind of primitive electronic toy I got for my daughter in the early 80s that did that.

Comment: As kids, if we drank a lot of fizzy lemonade, aunties used to say 'you'll go off pop!"

Comment: @MichaelHarvey nice ambiguity.