# What is the specific usage of the expression, "Boom goes the dynamite"? and why is it still frequently used in a grammatically awkward way?

Tags: grammar

Is there anyone who could briefly explain the specific usage of the famous blooper ***"Boom goes dynamite"***? And is it still OK to use the expression in a formal writing?

Comment: It's a non-standard rap lyric.

Comment: The reason for it becoming popular is possibly out-of-scope for this site...and ny quick google search shows "Boom goes _the_ dynamite.

Comment: @Cascabel - actually when and how an expression gained or lost currency is on topic on ELU.

Comment: @66974 If it has reasonable currency outside the song etc it appeared in. I'm not convinced there's much evidence for that (and OP's lack of any supporting evidence makes the question closable).

Comment: I wouldn't include this in a formal paper, say like a thesis, or a project summary, or an RFP unless I was dead sure it would be ok with the folks reading it. The same goes for any other popular phrase. You do so at your peril.

Comment: I think this goes back to when children are first learning how to read - they read picture books with captions like, *'Moo,' says the cow.*

Comment: @CanadianYankee We had a "famous" question dealing with that maybe a year ago, but it was :"The cow goes moo".

Comment: @Cascabel - Aha! I found this: [**Is “to go + (onomatopoeia)” a recognized pattern?**](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/549832/is-to-go-onomatopoeia-a-recognized-pattern/549833#549833)

Comment: Just found it at   [Why did Ylvis use “go” instead of “say” in phrases like “Dog goes 'woof'”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/486885/why-did-ylvis-use-go-instead-of-say-in-phrases-like-dog-g)...One of the answers (since deleted) cited Lou Reed, which some users found objectionable and questioned [on meta](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12046/is-using-colored-girls-as-an-incidental-example-offensive-or-unwelcoming) @CanadianYankee

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is an informal expression generally used to express satisfaction at something that’s gone the way you expected:

***[boom goes the dynamite:](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/Boom+goes+the+dynamite!)***

> (interjection) An exclamation used to emphasize when something exceptional has happened, especially when it occurred exactly as one intended. (The phrase was popularized after a video of Ball State University student Brian Collins uttering it during a collegiate sportscast went viral on the internet.)

> - *A: "You've got to use the sniper rifle to take out the guards in the tower, or else you'll never beat this level!" B: "OK, let me just line up my scope and—boom goes the dynamite!" A: "Hey, nice shot!"*

You can find other usage examples here on  [Google Books.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=boom%20goes%20the%20dynamite&year_start=2000&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&case_insensitive=true)

Comment: This answer is pretty much the basic research that the OP should have done in the first place. If the phrase  has become popular through non-standard rap lyrics then I think that makes it off-topic. BTW...not my down-vote.

Comment: @Cascabel - first  time user, be nice policy. Thank you!!!

Comment: @joe Before giving up entirely, think about how you can re-phrase the question to bring it on topic. Also, deleting a question that already has an answer could have an impact on privileges here...my suggestion is to let it perk for a bit.

Comment: @Cascabel, thanks I did some revision on the question. Hopefully it sounds better.

Comment: How am I being not nice? I have been trying to help the OP to bring their Q on-topic.

Answer (score 1):

***It's a fad.***

> an intense and widely shared enthusiasm for something, especially one that is short-lived and without basis in the object's qualities; a craze.

[-Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/fad)

...like the  hoola hoops and  Davie Crocket / Daniel Boone  coon-skin caps in the 1950s.

...as a 1960s Andy Warhol said,

> "In the future, everyone will be world-famous for 15 minutes."

---

***"Boom goes the dynamite"*** seems to be having such a moment:

It sounds similar to...

[Slam dunk!](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/slam-dunk)

or even ...

*bada bing,  bada boom*

...as popularized by the [American Mafia series *The Sopranos*](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/bada_bing) .

Those sayings were very popular for a while, but then died down in usage: still understood; just no longer fashionable.

If *"Boom goes dynamite"* survives 5 more years then possibly it will become known as a  saying.

Right now,

***It would not be acceptable in  an academic setting.***

Neologisms have no place in academic writing unless the topic concerns colloquial speech.

Comment: The expression was coined in 2005 and in 2021 we are still talking about it. It can be found in some slang dictionaries and it’s been used in a number of different contexts. I agree it is not acceptable in academic papers, but it appears to be more than a simple fad.